# Creating Dependable Custom Options Magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.8

How to create and import Dependable Custom Options  Ex:when we choose Gender Men in the Sex
it has to Show only Men's Sizes in the Sizes Option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by storing those size options in database with extra men and women fields and retrieve them with ajax.